# A new sandbox as the other one is 2 years old

Tags: discussion

[Sandbox for Proposed Challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1)

That is the current sandbox. It is getting old and a lot of pages. Should a high ranking user make a new post for sandbox?
The old sandbox is getting kinda clunky. With over 40 pages of posts it takes longer to load, and is getting bulky. With a new one we can experience the joy of starting fresh.

Comment: You should perhaps ellaborate why you think a new one should be made

Comment: I don't think there's a reason to split the sandbox in two. It would only serve to divide the attention of the community between both sandboxes, for no benefit (I can think of).

Comment: We just need to encourage people to look through what's already there and comment on answers. Or maybe a kick in the behind for a few of us lazy people (myself included) who have unposted challenges in the sandbox.

Comment: I agree that the sandbox is in dire need of cleaning but I don't think creating a new one is the optimal solution.

Comment: We used to do exactly this, but then we stopped retiring sandboxes because it [proved to be useless](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2061/3808). In any case, due to pagination, a sandbox with 1000 answers takes no longer to load than a sandbox with 30.

Comment: +Dennis put that as an answer if you like

Comment: Bear in mind you can [adopt abandoned sandbox posts](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2090/can-we-make-use-of-abandoned-sandbox-posts/2091#2091) yourself.

Comment: Yeaaasssss! They do the hard part I just fix em up and post :P

Comment: @doorknob unless you're on the mobile app where it takes so long to load it's unusable.

Comment: @Doorknob what do you do when you cannot comment on the OP's post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the answer is no. Just clean up your post!